# Last 5 minutes on Runtime Datatable

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have runtime Datatable. U update the datatable every seconds.

I want to keep just last 5 minutes on Datatable. Is there any way to do it ?

Comment: U need 2 rd [Ask] + take th [tour]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a column in the DataTable and save the time stamp of the insertion. You can loop thru the rows and remove the older than 5 minutes ones